# source code in c# for certificateless cryptography (mCL-PKE)

Tags: mcl

may I ask for some help on the source code for mCL-PKE in C#?

I have seen a few papers that introduce the concept for proposed cloud sharing system, but I still have not found any of the source code yet for it seems this concept is quite new. I'm not into proving how the algorithm works, but rather just applying the source code into the system. Thank you so much!

Some of the papers:
An Efficient Certificateless Encryption for Secure Data Sharing in Public Clouds
http://docs.lib.purdue.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1621&context=ccpubs

Encryption of secure data by mCL-PKE technique for the effective storage and retrieval in public cloud
http://www.ijiiet.com/papers/2015/May/E1536.pdf

Certificateless Public Key Cryptography  www.iacr.org/archive/asiacrypt2003/12_Session11/28_118/28940457.pdf

Comment: So you basically want someone to implement a new crypto algorithm you don't understand for you. Pretty bad idea to begin with. Also, security considerations (which you don't care about obviously) aside, this is not a code writing service.

Comment: Erm, no, i'm just asking if anyone have seen any certificateless encryption code anywhere. Or if anyone have any links to learn how to write codes from cryptography algorithms. I do understand like how the keys combine and produce another, but I don't know how to build codes out of them. And the security, the system is just a simulator to explain how the concept would work on it. Or would you kindly give some advice? Thank you!

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, unless you have a serious background in cryptography and software development, let it go. Other than that: When such a system is reliably implemented, you will find it via search engines (or papers will mention the implementation). It does not yet seem anywhere close to usable; yet generally interesting. As a simulation, a mockup interface might do.

Comment: I admit I am not very experience in the software world, but I am willing to learn because the concept is interesting. And the simulation would need to show how the concept would work, looking from the back end. I do see as well a system made using the mCL-PKE concept in youtube, and it doesn't seem to be a mock up one (unless I’m wrong about this). There are also papers that mention it, like the ones above, but some (such as the second one) is not clear enough. With my limited experience, I would love to hear advices from people like you too. Thank you!

Comment: Erm, really no one have seen the source code? I really can't find it, that's why I'm asking for help here...